# Do empty body functions get optimized by clang?

Tags: function, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

Something like this:

```
static void MyFunction(int x, int y) {};
```

Will Clang optimize them away when called?

Comment: Why not write a simple example and check it out on your own? It's the best way to learn. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the optimization level. If you have no optimizations then [you'll probably still end up with a function](https://godbolt.org/g/xCic1U). However, even with `-O` [you'll see it disappear](https://godbolt.org/g/w6sQAZ). If your function were not marked `static` it would be a bit more complicated because the function would need to exist for other translation units, so you might [see an empty body](https://godbolt.org/g/MPXXaG), and the call to it elided in the same TU, but the function itself must still exist.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, that [empty body](https://godbolt.org/g/MPXXaG) you mention should be removed by the linker if it is not actually used in other TUs.

Answer (score 2):

Given the code:

```
/* Optmizing empty functions */

  static void myFunc(int x, int y); 

  int main(void)
  {
      int x=1, y=2;

      myFunc(x, y); 

      return 0;
  }

static void myFunc(int x, int y)
{
      ;   
}
```

The assembly generated by each optimization level an be seen below:

### GCC - Optimization level 0 with -g (debug)

- gcc emptyfunc.c -g -O0 -o emptyfunc.x

  ```
  Dump of assembler code for function main:
     0x0000000000000660 <+0>:     push   %rbp
     0x0000000000000661 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
     0x0000000000000664 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
     0x0000000000000668 <+8>:     movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
     0x000000000000066f <+15>:    movl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
     0x0000000000000676 <+22>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%edx
     0x0000000000000679 <+25>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
     0x000000000000067c <+28>:    mov    %edx,%esi
     0x000000000000067e <+30>:    mov    %eax,%edi
     0x0000000000000680 <+32>:    callq  0x68c <myFunc>
     0x0000000000000685 <+37>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
     0x000000000000068a <+42>:    leaveq
     0x000000000000068b <+43>:    retq
  End of assembler dump.
  ```

### GCC - Optimization level 1

- gcc emptyfunc.c -O1 -o emptyfunc-gccO1.x

  ```
  Dump of assembler code for function main:
     0x0000000000000660 <+0>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
     0x0000000000000665 <+5>:     retq
  End of assembler dump.
  ```

### GCC - Optimization level 2, 3, Os (size), Og (debug) and Ofast

- gcc emptyfunc.c -O2 -o emptyfunc-gccO2.x
- gcc emptyfunc.c -O3 -o emptyfunc-gccO3.x
- gcc emptyfunc.c -Os -o emptyfunc-gccOs.x
- gcc emptyfunc.c -Og -o emptyfunc-gccOg.x
- gcc emptyfunc.c -Ofast -o emptyfunc-gccOfast.x

  ```
  Dump of assembler code for function main:
     0x0000000000000530 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
     0x0000000000000532 <+2>:     retq
  End of assembler dump.
  ```

### Clang - Optimization level 0 with -g (debug)

- clang emptyfunc.c -o emptyfunc-clangO0.x -g -O0

  ```
  Dump of assembler code for function main:
     0x00000000004004c0 <+0>:     push   %rbp
     0x00000000004004c1 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
     0x00000000004004c4 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
     0x00000000004004c8 <+8>:     movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
     0x00000000004004cf <+15>:    movl   $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)
     0x00000000004004d6 <+22>:    movl   $0x2,-0xc(%rbp)
     0x00000000004004dd <+29>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%edi
     0x00000000004004e0 <+32>:    mov    -0xc(%rbp),%esi
     0x00000000004004e3 <+35>:    callq  0x4004f0 <myFunc>
     0x00000000004004e8 <+40>:    xor    %eax,%eax
     0x00000000004004ea <+42>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
     0x00000000004004ee <+46>:    pop    %rbp
     0x00000000004004ef <+47>:    retq
  End of assembler dump.
  ```

### Clang - Optimization level 1, 2, 3, Os (size), Ofast, Oz (size II)

- clang emptyfunc.c -o emptyfunc-clangO1.x -O1
- clang emptyfunc.c -o emptyfunc-clangO2.x -O2
- clang emptyfunc.c -o emptyfunc-clangO3.x -O3
- clang emptyfunc.c -o emptyfunc-clangOs.x -Os
- clang emptyfunc.c -o emptyfunc-clangOfast.x -Ofast
- clang emptyfunc.c -o emptyfunc-clangOz.x -Oz

  ```
  Dump of assembler code for function main:
     0x00000000004004c0 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
     0x00000000004004c2 <+2>:     retq
  End of assembler dump.
  ```

As you can see, yes, of course it will remove the empty function.

Comment: Your code formatting isn't working. Code blocks need to be indented *8* spaces when they're part of bulleted lists. (That's 4 more than the normal 4 spaces of indent.)

Comment: Thanks. It was really not my fault. I didn't use ANY indentation, because I used `\`\`\`` to mark the block. It should work no matter where. But anyway, since it seems to be a bug, I've removed the 3 crase signs and added indentation to all lines. A pain to do, instead of just opening `\`\`\`` pasting code and closing with `\`\`\``

Comment: ``` is not a thing. It is not used to mark blocks. The only place you use backticks is to get inline code formatting; this uses a single backtick at the beginning and another one at the end of a string of text. For *block* code formatting, indentation is always required. It's normally 4 spaces in front of each line, except inside of an ordered/unordered list, where the number of required spaces is doubled to 8. (Tabs also work, where 1 tab is equal to 4 spaces, but everyone knows spaces are better than tabs. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, as long as the definition is visible to the compiler at the call site. Since you have declared it `static` that is probably always going to be true.

Answer (score 0):

yes of course with -O3 (actually any != 0)